# Missing this pagelayout in the site settings page layout list: (welcome page) search results

Tags: page-layout

I am using sp 2010. I am missing the page layout "(welcome page) search results" in the site settings page layout list.

[image]

this is the page layout gallery and here it is available
[image]

It is already published and approved. What am I missing?

Comment: I am using SP2013. In a site collection I can find "search result" layout but in another site collection I cannot find. Both SCs are under same web application. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to force activate features for it to show up. Have you tried this from sp-powershell as admin?

```
stsadm -o activatefeature -filename Name.Of.The.Feature.Folder\Feature.xml -url https://authoring.mysite.com/ -force
```

Good luck/Jesper Wilfing